# 'FreshchatSDK/FreshchatSDK.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, freshchat

I'm using Freshchat SDK (0.10.12) in Flutter but there is an error

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'FreshchatSDK/FreshchatSDK.h' file not found
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/freshchat_sdk-0.10.12/ios/Classes/FreshchatSdkPlugin.m:4:8
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?